# How fill an empty collection of object with another collection values in C#

Tags: c#

I have a object As a collection that need to fill another object(collection) with it and return it. I have this method that gets order collection Object and return billing collection object. But as billing collection is empty (Null) it pass foreach loop and it is not go inside to fill the object, how I can instantiate the billing collection so I can fill it.

```
 Input: Order Collection
 output: Billing Collection
```

So I need to fill out Billing collection with the values from Order collection

This is my code:

```
 public async Task<Collection<Billing>> MapOrderToBilling(Collection<Order> order)
    {
        Collection<Billing> items = new Collection<Billing>();
        foreach (var item in items) //it does not go inside this as items is null
        {
            item.adjustment = 10;               
            item.balance_ins = Convert.ToInt32(order.Select(o => o.Balance));
            item.balance_total = order.Select(o => o.TotalBalance).ToString();
     .....
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: So do you want to convert your ``Collection<Order>  collection to `Collection<Billing> `collection ?

Comment: Yes @Houssem - I need to fill billing collection object with the Order collection object and return Billing collection.

Comment: You should be looping over the `order` collection not the `items` collection which is empty not `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean converting your order object collection to billing object collection  you need to iterate on the orders object and not the billing one.

```
public async Task<Collection<Billing>> MapOrderToBilling(Collection<Order> orders)
    {
        Collection<Billing> items = new Collection<Billing>();
        foreach (var order in orders) //it does not go inside this as items is null
        {
            var billingObject=new Billing() // changed
            billingObject.adjustment = 10;               
            billingObject.balance_ins = order.Balance;
            billingObject.balance_total = order.TotalBalance;
            .....

            items.Add(billingObject) // changed
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: You need to address `var order in order`.

Comment: i let the old code because there is a logic of balance etc.. but yes.

Comment: I think the point is it should be `var order in orders`...?

Answer (score 3):

```
public async Task<Collection<Billing>> MapOrderToBilling(Collection<Order> order)
{
    Collection<Billing> items = (Collection<Billing>)order.Select(q => new Billing{
      adjustment = 10,
      balance_ins = Convert.ToInt32(q.Balance),
      balance_total = q.TotalBalance.ToString()
    });
    
    return items;
}
```

Basically, for each Order from `order` a new `Billing` will be created and inserted into the `items` list.

Comment: it's good to use linq , but when we are dealing with big objects , it's not good/Safe to deal with them using linq that's why the solutions i proposed is foreach loop that is clear to read/see.

Comment: But why tho? Under the hood, both of our solutions are the same, except LINQ is kind of more readable and takes less space

Comment: yes is the same , the point is about "more readable" i agree when some small object , but when big object, it's not more readable.
but it's the same and finally the choice of developer